# ordering nodes in Sankey diagram using rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts, sankey-diagram

I'm building a Sankey diagram in R using rCharts per https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_d3_sankey

Everything is fine except that I'd like to have control over the placement of the nodes. As I run the R script, it produces this:

[image: Sankey with nodes not in order]

I want all node-columns in ascending order, like the 2012 and 2013 node-columns. And like the image below (which I modified manually).
My `graph.data` is already sorted in the proper order as you can see:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(network.df[ , c("source","target","weight")])  
edgelist <- get.data.frame(g)    
colnames(edgelist) <- c("source","target","value")  
edgelist$source <- as.character(edgelist$source)  
edgelist$target <- as.character(edgelist$target)  
edgelist #<-edgelist is sorted by source
   source target value 
1  2012-0 2013-0     5 
2  2012-0 2013-1    21 
3  2012-1 2013-1    79 
4  2013-0 2014-0    42 
5  2013-0 2014-1    10 
6  2013-0 2014-2    13 
7  2013-0 2014-3    19 
8  2013-0 2014-4    12 
9  2013-0 2014-5     1 
10 2013-1 2014-0    29 
11 2013-1 2014-1    29 
12 2013-1 2014-2    23 
13 2013-1 2014-3    54 
14 2013-1 2014-4    17 
15 2014-0 2015-0     2 
16 2014-0 2015-1     8   
17 2014-0 2015-2     1    
18 2014-0 2015-3     1  
19 2014-0 2015-4     9  
20 2014-1 2015-0     5  
21 2014-1 2015-1    13  
22 2014-1 2015-2    68  
23 2014-1 2015-3     7  
24 2014-1 2015-4    66  
25 2014-2 2015-0     9  
26 2014-2 2015-2    23  
27 2014-2 2015-3    21  
28 2014-3 2015-3    56  
29 2014-4 2015-4     2  
30 2014-5 2015-5     1  
31 2015-0 2016-0     1  
32 2015-0 2016-1     1  
33 2015-0 2016-2     4  
<more rows omitted>
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$setLib('/rCharts_d3_sankey-gh-pages/rCharts_d3_sankey-gh-pages')
sankeyPlot$setTemplate(script = "rCharts_d3_sankey-gh-
pages/rCharts_d3_sankey-gh-pages/layouts/chart.html")
```

[image: Sankey with ordered nodes]

Comment: Have you tried saving the date fields as ordered vectors?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. I first ordered them when I created `network.df`, and then I passed them to `edgelist` as character vectors.

Comment: An ordered factor is different from a character vector. Here's a guide to creating an ordered factor: http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-work-with-ordered-factors-in-r/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried creating ordered factor variables, and I sorted in different ways, but R produced the same chart you see above, e.g. the un-ordered diagram.